# How to remove backslash on json_encode() function?

Tags: php, ajax, json, function, backslash

How to remove the `(\)`backslash on a string? when using `echo json_encode()` ?

For example:

```
<?php
$str = "$(\"#output\").append(\"<p>This is a test!</p>\")";

echo json_encode($str);
?>
```

note: When you echo $str, there will be no problem... but when you echo out using `json_encode()`, the `(\)`backslash will show up.

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: I ran into the same issues, turned out I was using `json_encode` twice on the same data, that was actually what was adding the backslashes.

Comment: JSON requires that quote characters in the data be escaped with backslashes, so if it is doing that it is functioning correctly. But why are you JSON encoding a string?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

```
json_encode($response, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Comment: And I just want to send it back on ajax. I just want the process done on php rather than on javascript.

Comment: sorry... how is this the "right" answer?? JSON is now used all over the place, not just in Javascript... it's simply a way to serialize data.  PHP bungles this (along with so much else) by adding completely superflous escapes to quotes that should not have them! the DATA should have escapes, not the quotes that wrap the data! And as it happens, it's essential to remove those quotes for this to work correctly since escaped quotes is NOT part of JSON. so... how DOES one do it??

Comment: Agree with the above commenter. There are lots of edge cases in the world of software development. This is not an answer.

Comment: If you actually put the json with backslashes in jsonlint it will return invalid json. I also do not think this is the correct answer.

Comment: JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES is for forward slashes, not quotes. e.g. \/these\/slashes\/are\/the\/target -- not \"these\"quotes\"are\"not\"the\"target

Answer (score 55):

Since PHP 5.4 there are constants which can be used by `json_encode()` to format the json reponse how you want.

To remove backslashes use: `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES`. Like so:

```
json_encode($response, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

View the PHP documentation for more constants and further information:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

List of JSON constants:

http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php

Comment: Should be available since 5.4? See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php)

Comment: I've Just discovered in PHP 5.6 that `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` works fine for forward slashes but does nothing for backslashes

Answer (score 13):

If you using PHP 5.2, json_encode just expects only 1 parameter when calling it. This is an alternative to unescape slash of json values:

```
stripslashes(json_encode($array))
```

Don't use it if your data is complicated.

Answer (score 9):

the solution that does work is this:

```
$str = preg_replace('/\\\"/',"\"", $str);
```

However you have to be extremely careful here because you need to make sure that all your values have their quotes escaped (which is generally true anyway, but especially so now that you will be stripping all the escapes from PHP's idiotic (and dysfunctional) "helper" functionality of adding unnecessary backslashes in front of all your object ids and values).

So, php, by default, double escapes your values that have a quote in them, so if you have a value of `My name is "Joe"` in your DB, php will bring this back as 
`My name is \\"Joe\\"`.

This may or may not be useful to you. If it's not you can then take the extra step of replacing the leading slash there like this:

```
$str = preg_replace('/\\\\\"/',"\"", $str);
```

yeah... it's ugly... but it works.

You're then left with something that vaguely resembles actual JSON.

Answer (score 7):

I just figured out that `json_encode` does only escape `\n` if it's used within single quotes.

```
echo json_encode("Hello World\n");
// results in "Hello World\n"
```

And

```
echo json_encode('Hello World\n');
// results in "Hello World\\\n"
```

Answer (score 6):

Simpler way would be

```
$mystring = json_encode($my_json,JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes it's possible. Look!

```
$str = str_replace('\\', '', $str);
```

But why would you want to?

Answer (score 3):

As HungryDB said the easier way for do that is:

```
$mystring = json_encode($my_json,JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

**Have a look at your php version** because this parameter has been added in version 5.4.0

[json_encode documentation](http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-encode.php)

Answer (score 2):

I use the following to remove the slashes

```
echo json_decode($mystring, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not want to delete it. Because JSON uses double quotes " " for strings, and your one returns

```
"$(\"#output\").append(\"
This is a test!<\/p>\")"
```

these backslashes escape these quotes

Answer (score 1):

The best way you can remove slashes using **JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES** flag inside **json_decode()**

Example:

```
echo json_encode($str, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

You can use multiple flags in **json_encode()**.

Example:

```
json_encode($str, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES)
```

Answer (score 0):

All answers with advice to use `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` is totally wrong, as this flag doesn't affect **backslashes** (`\`) escaping, only usual **slashes** (`/`).

Actually, the only option is to replace double backslashes to single backslashes in the resulting string, like this:

```php
$str      = 'some \n text';

$encoded  = json_encode($str, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
$replaced = str_replace('\\\\', '\\', $encoded);

echo 'Backslashes doubled: ' . $encoded . '<br>';
echo 'Duplicates replaced: ' . $replaced;
```

This will output following:

```
Backslashes doubled: "some \\n text"
Duplicates replaced: "some \n text"
```