# Why api response is comeing back with backslashes .How to avoid it

Tags: json, api, codeigniter

I have a category Table. I want to get all these data of the category table but the API response coming back with a backslash. How to avoid this backslash.

```
public function category_get($id = 0) {

        $categories = $this->category_model->getRows($id);
        // Check if the user data exists
        if(!empty($categories)){
            // Set the response and exit
            //OK (200) being the HTTP response code
            $this->response($categories, REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);

        }else{
            // Set the response and exit
            //NOT_FOUND (404) being the HTTP response code
            $this->response([
                'status' => FALSE,
                'message' => 'No category was found.'
            ], REST_Controller::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
        }
    }

 {
        "category_id": "27",
        "category_name": "Household",
        "description": null,
        "digital": null,
        "banner": "category_27.jpg",
        "data_brands": "",
        "data_vendors": "",
        "subcategories": "[{\"sub_id\":\"121\",\"sub_name\":\"DABUR RED AYURVEDIC TOOTHPASTE 100GM\",\"min\":50,\"max\":50,\"brands\":\"\"},{\"sub_id\":\"122\",\"sub_name\":\"Toilet Cleaner\",\"min\":82,\"max\":82,\"brands\":\"\"},{\"sub_id\":\"123\",\"sub_name\":\"Agarbatti & Puja Essentials \",\"min\":120,\"max\":120,\"brands\":\"\"},{\"sub_id\":\"135\",\"sub_name\":\"toothpaste\",\"min\":80,\"max\":80,\"brands\":\"\"},{\"sub_id\":\"144\",\"sub_name\":\"deo\",\"min\":0,\"max\":0,\"brands\":\"\"}]"
    },
```

Comment: it looks like `subcategories` is a string instead of a proper array structure (but you should know it - if you have developed that code...)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove backslash on json\_encode() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7282755/how-to-remove-backslash-on-json-encode-function)