# Yii2, Corrupted JSON object saved in MySQL JSON field

Tags: php, mysql, json, yii2

In [yii2](/questions/tagged/yii2) I have an associative array, I try to save it in `JSON` type MySQL table's field. However, the saved value is corrupted JSON object with `\` back slashes.

[image]

The above screenshot from [phpmyadmin](/questions/tagged/phpmyadmin). I saving the data by the code below:

```php
// In the update action:
//...
if ($flag) {
                        $transaction->commit();
                        Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('success', 'Record has been updated!');
                        $this->savedi($model);
                        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
                    }
//...

private function savedi($model)
{
    $output = [];
    foreach ($model->invoiceItems as $i => $item){
        $output['items'][$i]['id'] = $item->item_id;
        $output['items'][$i]['title'] = $item->item->title;
        $output['items'][$i]['qty']   = $item->qty;
    }
    $model->saved = json_encode($output);
    $model->save();
}
```

I don't know why the JSON is corrupted like that?

Comment: Have a look into: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22648879/7889695

Comment: I have back slashes. and I tested it and the object's string in phpmysdmin still the same.

Comment: Now I see, that is complete normal, because special characters are escaped inside a MYSQL string.

If you load back your model and var_dump/echo/xdebug it, you will see the backslashes are gone.

Ref:
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/4c1cae3d6ddcf994478c0eb48df2bb63b338434a/framework/db/Query.php
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/4c1cae3d6ddcf994478c0eb48df2bb63b338434a/framework/db/Command.php#L468

Comment: It looks like double encode to me. Yii2 has some support for JSON fields and it's doing json_encode by itself. Try `$model->saved = $output` instead of encoding it yourself.

Comment: @MichalHynčica Oh Yes! that works fine. Thank you. Please add this hint as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string in question looks like double encoded JSON.

The yii2 has some [basic support](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/db-active-record.md#json-in-mysql-and-postgresql) for JSON fields which take care of encoding/decoding. So instead of calling `json_encode()` yourself you just need to assign array/object that should be encoded as it is.

```php
private function savedi($model)
{
    $output = [];
    foreach ($model->invoiceItems as $i => $item){
        $output['items'][$i]['id'] = $item->item_id;
        $output['items'][$i]['title'] = $item->item->title;
        $output['items'][$i]['qty']   = $item->qty;
    }
    $model->saved = $output;
    $model->save();
}
```