# php json_encode seems to be add escape chars with backslash. How to stop that?

Tags: php, json

I have back slashes that at messes up my JSON.  Here is my script:

```
    $path = "https://api.example.com/datasets/v1/horseman?access_token=[snip]";
    $include_path   = false;
    $opts = array('http' =>
        array(
            'method'  => 'GET',
            'header'  => 'Content-type: application/json',
        )
    );
    $context = stream_context_create($opts);
    $mydata = file_get_contents($path, $include_path, $context);
    $response = array(
        "data" => $mydata, //i need to do this to dump it into datatables.
    );
    echo json_encode($response,JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

For some reason, I am getting back slashes added as here is the output;

```
  "data": "[{\"owner\":\"horseman\",\"id\":\"cl5dibmasdasdadsxt\",\"name\":\"goryu\",\"description\":null,\"created\":\"2022-07-09T06:29:53.907Z\",\"modified\":\"2022-07-24T02:57:37.576Z\",\"features\":75,\"size\":16617,\"bounds\":[137.81081,36.658897,137.8403,36.684357]}...
```

This was a good read about [backslashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7282755/how-to-remove-backslash-on-json-encode-function).  Seems `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` is for forward slashed.  I am also hesitant to run `str_replace` as I would rather find the problem that a work around.

Here is the contents of `$mydata`:

```
[{"owner":"horseman","id":"cl5dirwerwerwe2ts1id4xt","name":"goryu","description":null,"created":"2022-07-09T06:29:53.907Z","modified":"2022-07-24T02:57:37.576Z","features":75,"size":16617,"bounds":[137.81081,36.658897,137.8403,36.684357]},....
```

Comment: Show what your $mydata contains.

Comment: @MarkusZeller thanks. I have added the value of $mydata.  I see.  It is already JSON, however, I need to add the entire JSON to data like...  {"data":[{"owner":"horseman","id":"kjsaflkjdsf"... i can see that I am not doing this right then.

Comment: @MarkusZeller Correct.  What I have done was wrong (and stupid).  I am trying to throw the entire JSON in {"data":[]} but cannot figure that out.

Comment: You json_encode() what is already JSON. That's why it is all escaped.